# Como modificar un datalist?

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap, typescript, datalist

Tengo un dataliste con bootstrap y angular.

```
<label>Empleado *</label>
<input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" placeholder="Selecciona...">
<datalist id="datalistOptions">
  <option *ngFor="let empleado of empleados" [value]="empleado.ID_Empleado" [(ngModel)]="idEmpleado">
     {{empleado.nombre}}
  </option>
</datalist>
```

Pero el problemas es que cuando seleccionas a una persona, se cambia el valor por el ID_Empleado.
Me gustaria que al seleccionar la persona se quedara el nombre vivisible y el pero que el tomara el valor del ID.

Asi es cuando lo busco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y hasta ahi todo bien pero cuando lo selecciono:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se cambia al valor del ID y quiero que se quede el nombre visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que está sucediendo aquí es que estás utilizando una tijera para querer cortar leña.

La etiqueta `<datalist>` es utilizada para dar una lista de valores pre-definidos a un `<input>`.

La interacción que vos deseas lograr es por medio de la etiqueta `<select>` en conjunto con la etiqueta `<option>`, las cuales contienen el atributo `value` que actuará de la forma que tú deseas.

Un ejemplo de uso es el siguiente:

```html
<select id="selector">
      <option value="" disabled hidden selected>Selecciona...</option>
      <option value="1">Uno</option>
      <option value="2">Dos</option>
      <option value="3">Tres</option>
</select>
```

Se mostrará una lista desplegable que te muestre los valores `Uno, Dos y Tres`, pero cuando selecciones uno de ellos el valor asociado al `<select id="selector"` corresponderá al atributo `value` de éste. En este caso se podría saber cual es la opción seleccionada haciendo un `document.getElementByID('selector').value` (Dará como resultados ""[Si no se seleccionó un valor], 1, 2 o 3)

Modificando tu caso el código debería quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
<label>Empleado *</label>
<select class="form-control" id="selector">
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Selecciona..</option>
    <option *ngFor="let empleado of empleados"
        [value]="empleado.ID_Empleado"
        [(ngModel)]="idEmpleado">
            {{empleado.nombre}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Chequeando el valor asociado al select de la siguiente manera: `document.getElementById('selector').value`

Aclaración: He agregado un atributo `id` a la etiqueta `<select>` para uso del ejemplo.

A modo extra, si deseas conservar un campo en el que se ingrese texto y a su vez tener el beneficio de utilizar los `<select>` te recomiendo el proyecto [Select2](https://select2.org/)

También te dejo referencia sobre las etiquetas comentadas en esta respuesta para que puedas verificar por medio de la documentación y no solo mi palabra. [Datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist), [Select](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) y [Option](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

Pd: En mi códigos de ejemplo pudo verse que agregué en todos los casos una opción como la siguiente:

```
<option value="" disabled hidden selected>Selecciona...</option>
```

Esto es más que nada para generar un 'placeholder' en las etiquetas `<select>` puede omitirse.